# Why am I getting RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE timeouts when there should be plenty of memory available for grants?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, memory-grant

We occasionally have queries time out due to `RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE` waits but there appears to be plenty of available memory for memory grants. For example, I'm able to see timeouts by executing two queries that ask for the maximum available memory grant of 15%. Only one out of two queries gets a grant and other unrelated queries end up waiting for grants. From `sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants`:

[image: dm_exec_query_memory_grants]

I believe that the root cause of the problem is that target memory is too low for the query-resource semaphore. From `sys.dm_exec_query_resource_semaphores`:

[image: dm_exec_query_resource_semaphores]

For reference, here is what healthy values for target memory look like for this server:

[image: dm_exec_query_resource_semaphores healthy]

How can I determine why this problem is happening? I would prefer to understand the root cause instead of restarting the Windows VM and waiting for it to eventually happen again.

The rest of this question is an attempt to provide relevant diagnostic information.

**Windows VM information:**

[image: VM info]

I don't see any large non-SQL Server memory consumers:

[image: resource monitor]

**SQL Server information:**

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64)
Mar 18 2018 09:11:49
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Max server memory is 12000 MB, min server memory is 0 MB, and LOCK_PAGES is enabled.

Resource Governor is enabled but the only change is to limit the max memory grant to 15% instead of the default value of 25%.

SQL Server has been running for 5 months and the problem started happening a few days ago. We've seen this same problem happen in the past.

A few columns from `sys.dm_os_sys_info`:

[image: sys.dm_os_sys_info]

Full output of `DBCC MEMORYSTATUS`: https://pastebin.com/tBMW3Uqa

First 1000 rows of the `memory_broker_ring_buffer_recorded` event from `system_health`. The problem started at around 8:41:00 AM local time: https://pastebin.com/uqnd7hyy

Comment: Can you collect the XE `query_memory_grant_wait_begin` and post the output?

Comment: the "problem" start when the majority of the worker are work, and so the number of query increases. A semaphore is used when a critical section cann only be accessed by one or few processes the sane resource are using. i would start to think about better hatdware and amigration to 2022